# Optimizing rank computation for very large sparse matrices

Tags: optimization, matlab, matrix

I have a sparse matrix such as

```
A =

   (1,1)        1
   (3,1)        1
   (1,2)        1
   (2,2)        1
   (1,3)        1
   (3,3)        1
   (4,3)        1
   (4,4)        1
```

The full matrix of `A` can see look like as following:

```
full(A) =

     1     1     1     0
     0     1     0     0
     1     0     1     0
     0     0     1     1
```

I want to find the rank of matrix `A` by fast way (because my matrix can extend to $10000 \times 20000$). I try to do it by two ways but it give the different result

1. Convert to full matrix and find rank using

   ```
   rank(full(A)) = 3
   ```
2. Find the rank using sprank

   ```
   sprank(A) = 4
   ```

The true answer must be 3 that means using first way. However, it take long time to find the rank,especially matrix with large size. I know the reason why the second way give 4 because `sprank` only tells you how many rows/columns of your matrix have non-zero elements, while rank is reporting the actual rank of the matrix which indicates how many rows of your matrix are linearly independent. `sprank(A)` is 4 but `rank(A)` is only 3 because you can write the third row as a linear combination of the other rows, specifically `A(2,:) - A(1,:)`.

**My problem is that how to find the rank of a sparse matrix with lowest time consumption**

Update: I tried to use some way. However, it reported larger time consumption comparison with rank function. Could you suggest to me other way?

```
%% Create random matrix
 G = sparse(randi(2,1000,1000))-1;
 A=sparse(G) %% Because my input matrix is sparse matrix
%% Measure performance
>> tic; rank(full(A)); toc
Elapsed time is 0.710750 seconds.
>> tic; svds(A); toc
Elapsed time is 1.130674 seconds.
>> tic; eigs(A); toc
Warning: Only 3 of the 6 requested eigenvalues converged. 
> In eigs>processEUPDinfo at 1472
  In eigs at 365
Elapsed time is 4.894653 seconds.
```

Comment: Have you tried MATLAB's sparse, rank-revealing QR factorization? It should just be `qr` on the sparse matrix, followed by counting the number of elements in the $R$ matrix greater than a numerical threshold (similar to that of `rank`); see [Tim Davis' paper for details](http://www.cise.ufl.edu/research/sparse/techreports/SPQR/spqr.pdf).

Comment: So, Could you suggest the matlab code to resolve my problem. My goal is find rank of sparse matrix with lowest time consumption?

Comment: What you're trying to do is expensive one way or the other. The $QR$ factorization Geoff already pointed out is one way, and is the central step in computing a singular value decomposition (SVD) that will also provide you with the answer. But it is expensive for large matrices, there is little you can do about. It's not enough to just count elements or similar.

Comment: My task is find the rank of a sparse matrix subject to smallest computation time. I show some function to find it. However, it take long time compare with rank function. Do you know other way?